# How to replace findViewById() with LayoutInflater.inflate() for a watch view stub

Tags: android, android-layout, android-service, wear-os

I have a watch app but am investigating replacing the activity with a system overlay window.

The standard way of inflating a wearable's layout is to use:

```
 WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
```

However, if I am no longer using the activity instead I will be creating the system  overlay window in a server. Searching for how to do this all the answers suggest using `LayoutInflator's inflate()` method. However that takes a resource as a parameter, not a resource id.

How can I a load the WatchViewStub without using findViewById()? 
Or is there a way of using findViewById() from within a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `findViewById()` in the `Activity` because you've set the content view (root view) via `setContentView()`. Now, when you are inflating the view, you will inflate the `View` that is a root, and then call `findViewById()` on that layout, example:

```
View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.some_layout, parent, false);
WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) rootView.findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
```